# How do I keep only files of my application in artifactory

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

I have artifactory `JFrog` configured.
I'd like that `artifactory` keep only files (jar,war,etc) of my application and not keep other files on disk.
Example:

**(Yes, keep on disk of artifactory)**

```
myapp.1.0-SNAPSHOT 

myotherapp.2.0-SNAPSHOT
```

**(No, when execute maven command, I'd like that artifactory not contains these files, so, maven will search in central repository)**

```
hibernatexxx

springxxxx

log4jxxxx
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you mean that you do not want to store any artifacts from the remote repository (remote sites, such as Jcenter / Maven-central). If so, you may want to configure the remote repository not to store artifacts locally. This is being done by going to the Artifactory UI -> Admin -> Remote Repositories -> Edit the desired remote repository you are using -> Advanced -> and unmark the "Store Artifacts Locally" checkbox.

This way, every request you will do for artifacts that are not stored in your local repositories, will be fetched from the remote server, but will not be stored. Your Artifactory will be used as a proxy to that repository.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Guy